# Integral curves of time dependent derivations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

Question: Given smooth manifold $M$, with algebra of smooth functions deoted by $C(M)$ let $D_t$ be a time-dependent derivation of $C(M).$ Let $\hat{D}$ be a derivation of $C(M\times \mathbb{R})$ given by

$$\hat{D}(F)|_{p, t} = D_t(\iota_t^*F)|_p + \frac{d}{ds}\bigg|_{s=t}(\iota_p^*F),$$
where $\iota_t(x) = (x, t)$ and $\iota_p(s) = (p, s)$ are inclusions $M\rightarrow M\times\{t\}\subset M\times\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \{p\}\times\mathbb{R}\subset M\times\mathbb{R}.$

Let $\Psi_t$ be a family of automorphisms of $C(M\times \mathbb{R})$ satisfying
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
  \frac{d}{ds}\bigg|_{s = t}\Psi_s &= \Psi_t \circ \hat{D},\\
\rho_0 = I.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Define $\phi_t:C(M)\rightarrow C(M)$ by 
$$\phi_t(f)_p = \Psi_t(f\otimes 1)(p, 0).$$
How can be proved that it satisfies 
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
  \frac{d}{ds}\bigg|_{s = t}\phi_s &= \phi_t \circ D_t,\\
\rho_0 = I,
\end{split}
\end{equation}

without transferring everything to the geometric setting and then taking pull-backs?

Notice that $\phi_t$ does satisfy the proposed ODE, so let me elavorate a bit on the strategy I would like to aboid. We can see ($D_t$) and $\hat{D}$ as (time-dependent) vector fields $X_t$ and $\hat{X}$ respectively. The family $\Psi_t$ of automorphisms must be of the form $\Psi_t = \psi_t^*,$ where $\psi_t$ is the flow of $\hat{X}.$ Then, since $\hat{X}$ has the form
$$\hat{X}|_{(p, t)} = (X_t(p), \partial t),$$
its flow $\psi_t$ has the form
$$\psi_t(p, s) = (G_t(p, s), s+t),$$
for some map $G_t:M\times\mathbb{R}\rightarrow M.$ 
Then $\rho_t(\cdot):= G_t(\cdot, 0)$ is the flow of $X_t,$ and thus, $\rho_t^*$ solves 
$$\frac{d}{ds}\bigg|_{s = t}\rho_s^* = \rho_t^*\circ D_t.$$
On the other hand, $\phi_t$ as defined above is just $\rho_t^*,$ so it satisfies the preoposed ODE.

So, my actual question is if that result can be proved by only looking at the properties of derivations and automorphisms, once I will need this result in a context where I have no longer the correspondence between diffeomorphisms and automorphisms of the algebra of functions, namely in a formal case.